# rqt on MacOSX fails to start [ImportError?]

Tags: python, rosdep, homebrew, rqt, ros-groovy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I followed Homebrew source installation of Groovy on MacOS 10.7.5 and when i'm trying to run rqt i get the following error:

```
ImportError: numpy.core.multiarray failed to import
'import sitecustomize' failed; use -v for traceback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/rosdep2/__init__.py", line 34, in <module>
    from __future__ import print_function
ImportError: No module named __future__
[rospack] Error: could not find python module 'rosdep2.rospack'. is rosdep up-to-date (at least 0.10.4)?
[librospack]: error while executing command
terminate called throwing an exceptionAbort trap: 6
```

What is wrong? Can you help me?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/60715/rqt-on-macosx-fails-to-start-%5Bimporterror?%5D/) by [Tsirif](https://answers.ros.org/users/4683/tsirif/) on ROS Answers with karma: 106 on 2013-04-15

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

That is a very odd error, google'ing around it might be related to corruption of Python cache files?

http://askubuntu.com/questions/206955/update-manager-wont-open-error-related-to-pythonverbose

In the mean time you should make sure you have the latest version of `rosdep`:

```
sudo pip install -U rosdep
```

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2013-04-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0